# Pig: Outer join on more than 2 relations

Tags: join, apache-pig, bigdata

I want to do an outer join involving 3 tables. I tried with this:

```
features = JOIN group_event by group left outer, group_session by group, group_order by group;
```

I want all the rows of group_event to be present in the output even if one or neither of the other 2 relations have a match for that.

The command above is not working. Obviously since it is not supposed to work (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#JOIN+%28outer%29)

```
Outer joins will only work for two-way joins; to perform a multi-way outer join, you will need to perform multiple two-way outer join statements.
```

The split works and can be done like:

```
features1 = JOIN group_event by group left outer, group_session by group;
features2 = JOIN features1 by group_event::group left outer, group_order by group;
```

Any ideas to do this in a single command? (Would be useful if am joining even more number of tables)

Answer (score 1):

I think at some point, we need to trust the documentation, don't try single command multiple outer join.

Why? How should the following line work?

```
JOIN a BY a1 LEFT OUTER, b BY b1, c BY c1
```

Is the `LEFT OUTER` working for both tables, or just the first one? If the former, then should the `LEFT OUTER` between `b` and `c` remove all records not matched in `b`? Or in `a`? The more you look for it, the less sense it makes, doesn't it?

What you want to do is the `JOIN` the relation `a` with `b` into `ab` and then `ab` with `c`. If you think about it, it is not natural to do it within a single command because of the intermediate state `ab`.